# Speaking of converting int type to String type in Java

Tags: java

Why sometimes cast will not work but `String.valueOf()` will? Aren't they all exist for same functionality of converting current type to String?
For example:

```
addgui.getIdField().setText(String.valueOf(jtable.getValueAt(rowNum, 0)));
```

here `jtable.getValueAt(rowNum, 0)` returns an Integer value and if I directly cast it to String it causes eroor, but String,valueOf works instead.

Comment: Please provide examples - bearing in mind that even if a cast compiles, it will only *work* if you're casting a `String` at execution time anyway...

Comment: Which cast? String.valueOf() is a static method that can be used according to its definition. - I do not understand the second sentence.

Comment: To better answer your question post an example where a cast doesn't work, but String.valueOf() does.

Comment: You can convert an `int` primitive to a String in many ways, but casting is certainly not one of them. When you use an Object in a String context, Java can call `toString()`.

Comment: "Cast" is actually three different things in Java: 1) convert "primitive" types to other "primitive" types with appropriate twiddling of sign and extension bits, 2) instruct the compiler that a reference is to an object of the specified class, inserting a runtime check to assure that the object is indeed of that class, 3) in limited circumstances cause the compiler to do "boxing" and "unboxing" of primitives.  Translating between the internal bit representation of a number and its external character representation is not one of those functions.

Comment: (I actually believe that users are done a serious disservice by not explicitly distinguishing between these entirely disparate meanings of the term/notation.)

Comment: (It's also true that getting ones head around the concept of the difference between "internal representation" and "external/displayable representation" is one of the most difficult tasks for the novice programmer.)

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the trouble, I edited with example now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `String.valueOf(Object)` invokes `Object.toString()`, creates a `String` out of it and assigns it to the the `Object`.

Casting will just assign `object2` to the `object1`, If both have same type it will work. Otherwise, the expression would throw a `ClassCastException`.
Example

```
    Object a1 = "abc";
    String s =(String)a1; //this works
```

But this shall give you a `ClassCastException`

```
    int b = 1;
    Object c = b;
    String s1 =(String)c;
```

Where as `String.valueOf()` converts whatever to pass to it as a `String`

Comment: Of course (and the confusing part), one can cast an `int` to a `char` without dealing with objects and with no chance of ClassCastException (since no classes are involved).  The two uses of "cast" are entirely different and resemble each other only in using the same (confusing) notation.

Comment: ya for example int b = 97; char c = (char)b; never gives you a ClassCastException. what is that feature for

Comment: It's an entirely different function from the casting of object references.  They look the same and both use the term "cast", but that's where the similarity ends.

Comment: Strange kingdom of the King Java

Comment: Other languages have the same confusion, some even worse.